# Project Euler #19 in R

Tags: r

I need help understanding why I am getting the wrong answer for Problem 19 of Project Euler.
The problem is: 
You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

> 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
>   Thirty days has September,
>   April, June and November.
>   All the rest have thirty-one,
>   Saving February alone,
>   Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
>   And on leap years, twenty-nine.
>   A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
>   How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

```
#rm(list=ls())
days=seq(from=as.Date("1900/1/1"), to=as.Date("2000/12/31"), by="month")
firstSundays=days[weekdays(as.Date(days))=="Sunday"&months(as.Date(days))=="January"]
length(firstSundays)
```

The answer it gives me is 14 and when I look at firstSundays it gives me:

```
[1] "1905-01-01" "1911-01-01" "1922-01-01" "1928-01-01" "1933-01-01"
[6] "1939-01-01" "1950-01-01" "1956-01-01" "1961-01-01" "1967-01-01"
[11] "1978-01-01" "1984-01-01" "1989-01-01" "1995-01-01"
```

I don't understand what is going on here. Could someone please explain? I am fairly new to R and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your code is very good!  The formulation in the question is confusing (to the non native speaker as me) - but if you adjust for the following it will work: 1) the date range starts at 1901 (not 1900), 2) it asks for any months (not only Jan)

Comment: Thank you! I feel bad for wasting your time now...I can't believe I read the problem wrong lol.

Answer (score 5):

To compute it in R you could do as follows:

```
firsts_of_months <- seq(as.Date("1901-01-01"), as.Date("2000-12-01"), by = "1 month")
sum(weekdays(firsts_of_months) == "Sonntag") # use == "sunday" or your local language
```

Comment: Project Euler asks to not publish the answers. Would you mind to (at least) remove the numeric answer from this post?

Comment: @bdecaf, sure - didn't know that.